# How to get params in action in ZendFramework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

I have configured a route in my `module.config.php` to handle two parameters , 
here is the content of the file module.config.php , i put just the definition of the routes ( same routes ) :

**updated :**

```
 'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'Products' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/application/admin/products[/:id]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Admin',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'productsList' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/application/products/productsList[/:type][/:id]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Products',
                        'action' => 'productsList'
                    ),
                ),
            ),

            'Emplacement' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/application/support/listeEmplacementsSupport[/:pkSupport]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Support',
                        'action' => 'listeEmplacementsSupport',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'application' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/[:controller[/:action[/:id][/:dr]]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

And I build a link in the view using the following

```
<a href="/application/products/productsList/mandan/<?php echo $coreg['idProduct']; ?>" >
    <img height='20' src="/img/mail-recevoir-32.png" alt='products' />
</a>
```

To get one parameter I use

```
$param = $this->params('id');
```

Comment: And `$param = $this->params('type');` doesn't works?

Comment: nop , it doesn't ,  when i did $this->params('id') i get the value of the type param , and the value of the id i don't get it ...

Comment: Your route is defined as a `literal` route, this really should be `segment`. Are you sure this route is even the one being hit? If your controller action is executed you can check by echoing out  `$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();` from within the controller action.

Comment: Also, It won't resolve your issue, the standard (and more convenient way) of constructing links in the view is via the [URL view helper](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html#view-helper-url)

Comment: i did try sement for the type , but it didn't fix the problem .

Comment: i did the echo for the : $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName(); what should i get properly ? i get : application/default

Comment: That means you are not hitting the correct route, the result should include `productsList`, this is most likely beacuse you have a route definition that is more generic (`application/default`) being matched before. Update your question to include all the routes (ideally `application` and `products`).

Comment: i 've update the question.thanks for taking a look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes are matched in the ['Last in first out' LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29) order.

[The relevant section of the documentation states](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#simpleroutestack):

> Typically, routes should be queried in a LIFO order, and hence the reason behind the name RouteStack. [...] you will need to ensure that routes that **potentially overlap are registered such that the most specific match will match first (i.e., register later)**

Therefore based on you current configuration, as all the routes are register at the top level, the last route (`application/default`) is being checked and then subsequently matched first, before the `productList` is given a chance.

Also because `application/default` defines an optional `id` parameter as the first argument this is the reason that you get the value of the `type` param when using `$this->params('id')`.

**Soultion**

The easiest solution is just to reorder the routes; moving the `application` route right to the top of the definition should work.

The order should be the following

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(

        'application' => array(
            // .. same
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    // .. Same
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'Products' => array(
            // ..same
        ),
        'productsList' => array(
            // ..same
        ),

        'Emplacement' => array(
            // ..config
        ),

    ),
),
```

You could alternatively give each route a priority, regardless of the order, however I think It would make more sense to keep them in a natural order to save confusion in the future.

**While I'm here**

I mentioned in my comment you incorrectly used a `Literal` route rather than a `Segment`. You have this same issue with the the `Products` route definition. If a route is literal it will only match on the *exact* value (so you would need `/[:id]` in the URL).

```
/application/admin/products[/:id]
```

Therefore you will also need to update this route to a `segment` in order for the product id to be regarded as a parameter.

Lastly, there is a easier way of constructing URL's in the view, using the [URL view helper](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html#view-helper-url). Your view script code would be changed to

```
<?php
    $type = 'mandan';
    $id   = $coreg['idProduct']; 
?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('productsList', compact('type', 'id')); ?>">
    <img height='20' src="/img/mail-recevoir-32.png" alt='products' />
</a>
```